# Sorting the items in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, combobox

I have a combobox binded to an observable collection. I am using CollectionViewSource to sort the items in the combobox alphabetically.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="EmployeeViewSource" Source="{Binding LstEmployeeDetails}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="EmployeeName" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

And then I bind it to my combobox like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbboxEmployeeName" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmployeeViewSource}}"/>
```

The problem is I have two items in the collection that I don't want to sort. They are

--Select-- and "Add New". I want that these two items should always be displayed on top and then the rest of the items should be sorted alphabetically. Also, when I add a new item to the list, it should get sorted automatically.

Comment: See this link: http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/441#.U4Wz_z9klo8

Comment: @qqbenq link seems to be no longer valid

Comment: Stored version of the linked blogbost on wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140709001525/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/441#.WEVPMaIrLIE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind your `ComboBox` to an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel and sort it in code:

**C#:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> List { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        List.Add("Select");
        List.Add("Add New");

        foreach (var employee in LstEmployeeDetails.OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeName))
        {
            List.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbboxEmployeeName" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>
```

Comment: Correct. This is exactly what i had typed half way .. :|
Kudos.!!
Do you know of any way which will let me bind through XAML and still let the "add new" and "select" be at the top?

Comment: Maybe see the qqbenq's comment, it can be a good solution too.

Comment: Going by your solution, when I add a new employee to the list, it gets added to the bottom. I want that the new item added in the list should also get automatically sorted.

Comment: Yes indeed, if you use this solution you'll have to clear and reorder your list when adding a new employee.